# Is Galaxy S3 always disclosing an WiFi SSID?

Tags: networking, wi-fi, router, security

I read tons of articles about how is it bad do hide SSID because client devices can disclose the network parameters by constantly "pinging" it when not in range. Ok, here is the client the bad guy, not the access point.

Ok. Then I take my Samsung Galaxy S3 phone, go to the WiFi network settings and do not see any checkbox of the kind "Connect even if SSID is hidden". But my network IS hidden and SGS3 IS connecting to it. Does it mean that SGS3 is always automatically ready to disclose WiFi parameters, no matter whether SSID is hidden or not?

There is a small bit of hope left:

May be the way how the network was added influences SGS3 WiFi client behaviour?
Because this network is hidden, I had to add it manually. May be when a WiFi network is broadcasting its SSID and I only have to choose it from the list, the phone behaves then differently and doesn't constantly try to discover the network?

**Please do not write that I shouldn't hide SSID. It will deflect the discussion in an unwanted mainstream direction. There are tons of such suggestions in the Internet.**

So, using the link provided by Andrew T. I found out that Android prior to v9 is always sending probe requests to the not available saved networks, and this behavior was made changeable only in Android v9+.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK hiding the SSID only changes behaviour for initial connection as one has to know the SSID to be able to connect instead of just choosing from the list.

Also the WiFi will at some point confirm its network name to devices who would try to connect to it which could be intercepted by a third party that would try to connect to it.

In my opinion hiding the SSID is just a tiny security by obscurity measure that only protects from everyday users.

Here is some interesting read about the situation with some examples:

[hidden wifi ssid: How to know the name of a wireless network with no SSID](https://www.acrylicwifi.com/en/blog/hidden-ssid-wifi-how-to-know-name-of-network-without-ssid/)